# Apply Live GpuImage on CameraView

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.6, gpuimage

i´m currently working on a camera filter app which should use the GPUImage framework.
I already got the custom camera working, now i want to apply only one filter on the uiview that i got. So the filter is constantly on my UIView, and it should save the pictures with the filter.
I would be really thankful if u can help me

Answer (score 4):

The main Readme for the project describes the exact steps you need for this:

```
GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomShader"];
GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight)];

// Add the view somewhere so it's visible

[videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
[customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

First, you create the GPUImageCamera instance that will pull live video. Then, you create whatever filter you want (a custom one in the above code) and attach it as a target of your camera. Finally, you set up a GPUImageView instance where the filtered camera feed will be displayed and make that in turn a target of the filter. Video frames will flow down the pipeline from the camera to the filter to the view as a result.

If you instead want to be able to save photos from the camera, you'll want to use a GPUImageStillCamera instead of the video camera instance above. The still camera will provide a video preview from the photo camera and will let you capture full-resolution photos on demand.

Again, all of this is clearly explained in the documentation that comes with the framework (and is displayed on the front page of the GitHub project).